# how can merge object

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregate

this my data seem  data
I want items array in object after amount result so below

```
----------
[
{
 employeeName: 'វី រឿន',
 docStudyFee: 415.24,
 docBusFee: 50,
 docSaleFee: 10,
 amount: 475.24 },
 { items: 
       [ 
         [Object],
         [Object],
         [Object],
       ] 
 },
 ]
```

I want to get result like this Please help me

```
 [{
 employeeName: 'វី រឿន',
 docStudyFee: 415.24,
 docBusFee: 50,
 docSaleFee: 10,
 amount: 475.24 ,
    { items: 
           [ 
             [Object],
             [Object],
             [Object],
           ] 
    },
}]
```

Comment: Do you have two distinct objects? Or an array of different types?

Comment: sorry it two array i want it only one array [{
 employeeName: 'វី រឿន',
 docStudyFee: 415.24,
 docBusFee: 50,
 docSaleFee: 10,
 amount: 475.24 ,
     items: 
           [ 
             [Object],
             [Object],
             [Object],
           ]     
}]

Comment: @phan chanra please don't put this into a comment but attach it to your question, so it is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given than the two arrays are already sorted as needed you can:

```
var arr1 = [{employeeName: 'វី រឿន', docStudyFee: 415.24, docBusFee: 50, docSaleFee: 10, amount: 475.24}, ...]
var arr2 = [{ items: 
       [ 
         [Object],
         [Object],
         [Object],
       ] 
}, ...]

var result = []

for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
  result.push(Object.assign(arr1[i], arr2[i]))
}
```